# JQuery Function that hides all tags whose functions match a certain pattern

Tags: jquery, regex, css-selectors, toggle

I am new Jquery and have written a toggle function that looks like this:

```
         $('.one-toggle').click(function(){ 
             $('.one-graph').toggle();
         });
```

Basically I want to change my two CSS selectors so that they match any tag that has one-toggle and one-graph. I don't want the selector to require a direct match. Regex maybe?

Comment: I believe what you're asking for would be solved with the "Attribute Contains" selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Could you describe the behavior you want in more detail?  For example, show a few different elements that you would want matched by your selector?

Comment: I mean that I want it too match class = "one-toggle132414-river" I am in essence looking for a fuzzy match

Comment: Pat, attribute contains was what I was looking for. I up-voted your comment, but if you re-write it as an answer, I will select it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match tags that have both class names, you just need this:

```
// cache the selector
var $elements = $('.one-toggle.one-graph').click(function(){ 
    // toggle all matched elements
    $elements.toggle();
    // or did you want to toggle just the clicked element?
    // $(this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a fuzzy match not an either or match. I mean that I want it too match class = "one-toggle132414-river"

Answer (score 1):

Just use the standard CSS selector separator:

```
$('.one-toggle, .one-graph').click(function(){ 
     $('.one-graph').toggle();
});
```